# Current associated with the orbital angular momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, atomic-physics

> Problem: For a 3d electron in an external magnetic field of 2.50×10−3 T, find
>
> (a) the current associated with the orbital angular momentum, and
>
> (b) the maximum torque.

Attempt:

[image: formula] because the electron is in the d orbital

[image: formula]

How do I know what the orbital radius of the electron is? Doesn't it depend on the number of protons?

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think here we HAVE to assume that the atom is in accordance to Bohr's model of hydrogen like atom. If that's the assumption we go with...We already know the formula for radius of a shell.